# Effect of poles on induction motor

Tags: motor

Why does the change in poles does not affect the torque?
Even if number of poles increased the torque remained to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

For any given motor, the available torque is basically proportional to the surface area of the rotor and the strength of the magnetic field in the gap between rotor and stator.

If you add more poles, the area of each one is reduced proportionally, and the total area remains the same.